# What tools to use to eliminate metadata in graphics files?

Tags: software-rec, image-manipulation

What tools can I use to delete all the EXIF, IPTC, XMP, etc metadata from graphics files?

Answer (score 3):

Try **exiftool** (which is written in perl):

https://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

usage:

```
exiftool -all= image.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

[jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) can be used to delete metadata from JPG files. The following command line options to jhead are available (quoting the man page for jhead below):

```
   -dc    Delete comment field from the JPEG header.  Note that the comment is not part of the Exif header.
   -de    Delete the Exif header entirely.  Leaves other metadata sections intact.
   -di    Delete the IPTC section, if present.  Leaves other metadata sections intact.
   -dx    Delete the XMP section, if present.  Leaves other metadata sections intact.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for [`exiv2`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/exiv2.1.html) to delete image metadata.

By default, the `exiv2` subcommand `rm` (or `delete`) removes Exif thumbnails and JPEG comments also, additional to the ones you mention (EXIF, IPTC, XMP):

```
$ exiv2 rm test.jpg
```

Use the option `-d` to delete only parts of the metadata.
From [`man exiv2`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/exiv2.1.html):

```
-d tgt Delete target(s) for the 'delete' action. Possible targets are:
       a : all supported metadata (the default)
       e : Exif section
       t : Exif thumbnail only
       i : IPTC data
       x : XMP packet
       c : JPEG comment
```